# Waiting for an object to be updated by another task C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I've read over many many posts about 'waiting' for a task... I can't seem to get this straight because it may be a twist on actually waiting for a task, i'm waiting for an object to be updated and if not timeout.

I'm using redis which in a seperate message handler correctly updates a list of basic acks/nacks when it receives them from the redis server. (too much code to post and not really relevant to this question).

The code in question is how do I call the below 'WaitForAck' method, where its duty is to check if the above list gets appended with the ack/nack it's waiting for.

So I want to be able to call 'WaitForAck' anywhere where it will wait for (7 seconds) if the list 'dic_DEAL_OUTPUTRESP_MessageQueue' gets appended by the seperate redis handler, basically blocking the user from moving forward but don't block any other threads such as the redis message handler thread waiting for its update.

I suppose i'm a bit confused if this should be any kind of await Task because I don't want it to be async?  I want the user to wait 7 seconds to see if it receives an ack/nack (list has a value) otherwise it goes on to notify user of a timeout (handled seperately).

Here is my 'WaitForAck' method:

```
    public static void WaitForAck(string origUuid)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            while (dic_DEAL_OUTPUTRESP_MessageQueue[origUuid] == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for Redis Ack");
                Task.Delay(1000);
                TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - dt;
                if (ts.TotalSeconds > iWAIT)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Thank you in advance

**EDIT: Added Call**

```
 private async void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Process trade entry / amendment
        if (ConfirmEntries() != 0)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
            return;
        }
        DefineDeal();

        // Attempt Commit
        DEAL_REQ dEAL_REQ_ADD = new DEAL_REQ();
        dEAL_REQ_ADD.msgTimestamp = ReturnUTCTime(DateTime.Now).ToString(sDATETIME_FORMATMS);
        dEAL_REQ_ADD.uuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        dEAL_REQ_ADD.commandKey = sMeFunction == sADD ? sDEAL_REQ_ADD : sDEAL_REQ_UPDATE;
        dEAL_REQ_ADD.listenChannel = sRPC_CHANNEL_OUTPUT;
        dEAL_REQ_ADD.payload = _fxTempDeal;
        // Build json msg
        string sJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dEAL_REQ_ADD);
        // Publish request
        // Prime response queue with guid in key
        dic_DEAL_OUTPUTRESP_MessageQueue.Add(dEAL_REQ_ADD.uuid, null);
        //Task.Delay(100);
        IDatabase db = redisConn.GetDatabase(redisDB);

        db.ListLeftPush(sRPC_CHANNEL_INPUT, sJson);
        //Task.Delay(100);
        //string s = db.ListLeftPop(sRPC_LB_INPUT);

        // Wait for ack 
        var value = await this.WaitForAck2(dEAL_REQ_ADD.uuid);

        // Received ack/nack
        if (value != null)
        {
            DEAL_RESP rESP = dic_DEAL_OUTPUTRESP_MessageQueue[dEAL_REQ_ADD.uuid];

            if (rESP.commandKey == sDEAL_REQ_ADD_ACK || rESP.commandKey == sDEAL_REQ_UPDATE_ACK)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else if (rESP.commandKey == sDEAL_REQ_ADD_NACK || rESP.commandKey == sDEAL_REQ_UPDATE_NACK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to " + sMeFunction + " this deal. Please contact support. Reason : " + rESP.payload.display_msg, sAPP_NAME, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort;
            }
        }
        // Timed out
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to " + sMeFunction + " this deal. Please contact support. Reason : Request Timeout", sAPP_NAME, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            dic_DEAL_OUTPUTRESP_MessageQueue.Remove(dEAL_REQ_ADD.uuid);
            dic_DEAL_TimedOut_MessageQueue.Add(dEAL_REQ_ADD.uuid, null);
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
    }

    public async Task<DEAL_RESP> WaitForAck2(string origUuid)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        while (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < (7 * 1000))
        {
            if (await this.sync.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7)))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (dic_DEAL_OUTPUTRESP_MessageQueue.TryGetValue(origUuid, out var value))
                    {
                        return value;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.sync.Release();
                }
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**FINAL**

````
   public static async Task<bool> WaitForReply(IDictionary dT, string 
   orig_uuid, int iWaitSec)
    {
        SemaphoreSlim sync = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        while (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < (iWaitSec * 1000))
        {
            if (await sync.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(iWaitSec)))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (dT[orig_uuid] != null)
                        return true;
                }
                finally
                {
                    sync.Release();
                }                    
            }
            await Task.Delay(250);
        }
        return false;
    }```
````

Comment: You can't introduce a callback to the method that does the updating?

Comment: i would look at the threading primitives in .net - such as `ManualResetEvent`

Comment: As I understand it: Your actuall problem is that you got a lockable resource. You want to start a process (that has to respect the lock) against that resource, even while it may be locked. That process should be able to wait (normal lock behavior) if it is locked, but also time out if aquiring the lock it takes really long (not normal lock behavior)?

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine, and that is just terrible. You swallow all exceptions. That is 2 cardinal sins of exception handling in one terrible line. As it is written, there should not even *be* a try block there. I got two articles on exception handling that I link often. They should help avoid you doing code like that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @itsme86 I don't believe I can do a callback?  as it is simply a pub/sub setup that is completely decoupled, ie: a process requests an update to server, server pubs an ack/nack this method waits for it... but it may never come

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks I will look into that...

Comment: @Christopher Yes, my problem is I want to simply wait for an update synchronously for another thread (redis pub/sub) to update the list.    As for error handling, this is code under dev and still in a pseudo state, the error handling is not relevant to the question but thanks for the insults

Comment: Your problam is unclear. Your cod uses resoruce defined outside it, like `dic_DEAL_OUTPUTRESP_MessageQueue` and `iWAIT`. It sounds very much like a XY problem. And stuff like this is a book example of things you want to do asynchronously. | Make a simple, complete, verifyiable example that showcases your issue. Then properly tell use your issues. And with issue I mean the X, not your selected Y.

Comment: His question is pretty straightforward although the having the cursors indicates it's in the UI which makes it tricky.  If not for the UI it would be easy to do with an autoresetevent. His example won't work in the UI either of course but that is why he's asking the question.

Comment: @Christopher i explain in the question pretty clearly what's happening outside of this but that is not in question.  iWait is simply an int defined elsewhere, as i said it is 7seconds and again not relevant.  My question is around designing a method thats duty is to check if the list is  updated for 7 seconds.  That is the goal, that is the question...posting a ton of redis server pub/sub code will not help.  Nothing else is happening, user clicks a button to add a record which is a pub/sub request, the sub replies with an ack... i'm waiting for that in "WaitForAck"..what are you unclear on?

Comment: @MX313 take out the line that adds the null value to the dictionary.  Then it should wait for the actual value.

Comment: I hope you are aware that the line `Task.Delay(1000);` inside the first code snippet does nothing. You are not `await`ing the task, so no delay occurs. Probably what you intended to write there is `Thread.Sleep(1000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting push back on your question because context of the threading requirements are not clear.  If this was simply two threads running in a service then a simple autoresetevent could be used to signal that new messages have been added to the queue and then that thread could respond.  But from your example it seems - due to the Cursor class usage - you're running in the UI thread which complicates it.  You can't block the UI thread.

I suspect there are better UI patterns to handle this than polling the queue for 7 seconds.  But if that is what fits with your current design then I think the following code would enable the async polling.   I tested this using a simple console app and the threading works as expected.  The outer class is not shown..

```
class MyClass 
{
    SemaphoreSlim sync = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    Dictionary<string, string> messages = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public async void OnButtonClicked(EventArgs sender)
    {
        string origUuid = string.Empty; // get key from button click?

        var value = await this.WaitForAck(origUuid);

        if (null != value)
        {
            /// display it somehow...
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> WaitForAck(string origUuid)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        while (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < (7 * 1000))
        {
            if (await this.sync.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7)))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (this.messages.TryGetValue(origUuid, out var value))
                    {
                        return value;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.sync.Release();
                }
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public async Task PushAck(string origUuid, string value)
    {
        await this.sync.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            this.messages.Add(origUuid, value);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.sync.Release();
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myform = new MyClass();

        var pub = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int index = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

                myform.PushAck(index.ToString(), "gotit").Wait();

                ++index;
            }
        });

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        var mymessage = await myform.WaitForAck("1");
        timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"message \"{mymessage}\" recieved in {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, I will take a look at this

Comment: @MX313  I've taken the UI bits out of your polling method, you'd call this from a async void button handler method and adjust your cursor or any other UI changes inside that.

Comment: where do I pick this code back up? Ie: currently I call WaitForAck and it does the waiting there, ie: it doesn't return until theres an answer ack/nack or timeout and continues with next line of // Wait for ack as follows:
            WaitForAck(dEAL_REQ_ADD.uuid);

            // Received ack/nack
            if (dic_DEAL_OUTPUTRESP_MessageQueue[dEAL_REQ_ADD.uuid] != null).         Since this new code falls right through and is async, where should I pick up its response as in when if (this.messages.TryGetValue(origUuid, out var value)) is true?  Thank you for help

Comment: Should I just use a sort of wait method such as Task output = Task.Factory.StartNew(WaitForAck); output.Wait(); ?

Comment: @MX313 no, don't block the UI thread with a wait.  I've added a button onclick handler.  You might have to invoke back to the ui thread to display the result.  You'll have to test or maybe someone else can respond.

Comment: This is for an entry form, so adding a new record, clicking ok... request is sent to pub/sub, user waiting to see if ack/nack is received...  i'm stuck basically i want to give the pub/sub 7 seconds to make an entry in my list, if not timeout.  The code above  you gave i'm trying to implement but it falls right through that with no response recieved, i want it to wait 7 seconds while its continually trying to access that value in the list to see if it has been received

Comment: @MX313 you have to await the call to WaitForAck. (Not wait but await as I showed in last edit)

Comment: I see your code edit thank you, i hve that implemented, it falls right through with a Id = 145, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

Comment: Ok I have all edited as provided, if I pause the code (to give the pub/sub the half a second or so to reply) this works, but if I let it run through I get an object ref not set as follows... so I don't see how it is 'waiting' the 7 seconds if this is happening...

Comment: @MX313 I've tested it from a simple console app, it works as expected.  Could you edit your question to show how you're calling it?  Also, the other thread, that is publishing to this queue, where does that run?

Comment: @MX313 and to be clear, OnButtonClicked, is not something you would call, it would be an example of your actual async button clicked handler.

Comment: I edited code above, it falls straight through, but if I break and it has time it proceeds correctly

Comment: the other thread runs on the main UI but spins off the redis pub/sub thread which all works fine...when an ACK is received it adds it to the queue..thanks for this help

Comment: @MX313 ok, so I added more code to show how it was tested.  I'm not quite sure how to debug what you've shown.  By falls straight through, you mean you get a null back immediately from WaitForAck2?

Comment: shouldn't it be waiting here var value = await this.WaitForAck2(dEAL_REQ_ADD.uuid); before proceeding to the if(value != null)?

Comment: yes it returns null immediately, the pub/sub takes about 200-300 ms so it is not in time

Comment: @MX313 if I increase the delay in the pub thread in my example, it times out after 7 seconds, so the loop seems to work correctly when I test it.  I didn't see anything in your code that should alter that, should be waiting.  Sorry, wish I could offer more help.

Comment: ok I will keep working with it...thanks very much for your time and help

Comment: @MX313 wait I think I do see it.. you "prime" the dictionary with a null value.  So it's got the value when you start waiting for it.  Only it's null.  So you're immediately finding it and returning the null value.

Comment: ah yes, checking on that, there's a reason I have that but will correct around that, thank you for your help...will confirm when working

Comment: it looks like its waiting the 7 seconds, but why would it be dismissing the open form, but when it returns from the 7 second wait (i'm forcing a wait) it returns to the correct place in code but the form has been dismissed...can't thank you enough for help...i'm going to mark this as answer

Comment: @MX313 from what I see in your code the form would only close when you set the dialog result.  But the UI thread is running so I don't know if there are other things that could cause it to close after you've awaited the results.

Comment: yes I will handle the form closing manually, I think it was set as a DialogClose button.  Thank you very much for the help today!